# Create a application like Visual studio object Browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, object, browser

I want to develop an application like Visual studio Object Browser, i.e. user will enter something like `System.Text` namespace or system classes.  After button click, we have to find out all classes, functions, properties etc. inside the "System.Text".

I tried the following, but that failed.

```
        Assembly SampleAssembly;
        SampleAssembly = Assembly.Load("System.Text");

        Type[] Types = SampleAssembly.GetTypes();
        // Display all the types contained in the specified assembly.
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (Type oType in Types)
        {
            str.Append(oType.Name.ToString() + "</br>");
        }
        divAsseblyData.InnerHtml = str.ToString();
```

Comment: yes,got error FileNotFound exception? line 2:SampleAssembly = Assembly.Load("System.Text");

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'System.Text' assembly; it is only a namespace inside mscorlib.dll. Rewrite your code to load mscorlib and navigate then to the System.Text namespace.

Comment: ok thank you Edwin sir..thats right!..In mscorlib.dll how can  i navigate System.Text or System.Web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'System.Text' is a namespace not an assembly so i assume you want to load the assembly 'System'.

To use Assembly.Load() with a string parameter you need to pass the fully qualified name of the assembly.

To obtain the fully qualified name you can do something like this:

```
Assembly SampleAssembly;
SampleAssembly = Assembly.Load(typeof(System.Activator).Assembly.FullName);
// get the type of some random object in the assembly (Activator) and then
// call .Assembly.FullName which returns the fully qualified name of the assembly
```

Or you can press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type "Assembly" and enter, then right click -> proprieties on the assembly which you need and set manually the proprieties in code in the format:

"mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"

```
SampleAssembly = Assembly.Load("mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");
```

Comment: That's an awesome tip for finding the name of an assembly!

Comment: ok thank you so much Razan Panda sir.can you share what to do next.!ie in mscorlib.dll how can i navigate System.Text or System.Web?

Comment: @Justin: what do you mean by navigate? what do you need to do?

Comment: @Razan : navigate means ie. actually i need to get all properties ,function name of a class.if user enter "String.Text.StringBuilder" class then i have to show them all properties and methods of that class.Please help me..!

Comment: @Justin: see the examples in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196504/in-c-is-there-anyway-to-determine-a-classs-members-at-runtime of how to get class members