# Get BaseTypes of an Assembly by Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, objectbrowser

im trying to develop an app. like vs ObjectBrowser and flow was something like this:
[stackoverflow.com/questions/6939400/create-a-application-like-visual-studio-object-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939400/create-a-application-like-visual-studio-object-browser)

now my problem was i cant find the method for calling all basetypes ...
something like:
[image]

instead i can only see "Object" as BaseType for Class ...

```
Q: Is there a way I can get all basetypes via reflection?
```

Comment: By "base types" you mean types, not presented in assembly or types from mscorlib? Anyway, you can get all types from assembly, then for each type take all their base types. which are not presented in assembly...

Comment: Reflection is nice for objects your application needs and loads naturally. If you want to analyze independent assemblies, I strongly recommend using something else, like Mono.Cecil. Don't try to use reflection-only loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Interfaces*** (`IComparable`, `IStructuralComparable` etc.) are not *base types*, since a base type can be *only one* (`Object` in your case). If you want to get all the *interfaces implemented* use

```
  Type tp = ... // type of interest

  Type baseType = tp.BaseType; // Base type
  Type[] interfaces = tp.GetInterfaces(); // Interfaces
```

Comment: 1more question, how about in this scenario? http://i59.tinypic.com/2eo8pat.png
 how to get Exception in SystemException?

Comment: @Elegiac: use `Type baseType = tp.BaseType;`